# Converting iOS YUV420 Image to RGB

Tags: flutter, image, rgb, color-space

I'm using Flutter to develop an object detection app for iOS and Android. I have images in the YUV420 format, and I need to convert them into an 'Image' object. To do this, I convert each pixel from YUV240 to RGB, and then use the Image library to set each pixel.

For Android, the following code works:

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

img.Image convertYUV420ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
  final width = cameraImage.width;
  final height = cameraImage.height;

  final yRowStride = cameraImage.planes[0].bytesPerRow;
  final uvRowStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
  final uvPixelStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerPixel!;

  final image = img.Image(width:width, height:height);

  for (var w = 0; w < width; w++) {
    for (var h = 0; h < height; h++) {
      final uvIndex =
          uvPixelStride * (w / 2).floor() + uvRowStride * (h / 2).floor();
      final index = h * width + w;
      final yIndex = h * yRowStride + w;

      final y = cameraImage.planes[0].bytes[yIndex];
      final u = cameraImage.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
      final v = cameraImage.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];

      image.data?.setPixel(w, h, yuv2rgb(y, u, v));
    }
  }
  return image;
}
```

However, iOS doesn't use images with 3 planes (it has 2), so I need to write a new function for YUV420 to RGB conversion for this.

I'm not very familiar with image formats and color spaces, but from what I have found, iOS stores the 'u' and 'v' data in a single plane. However, I cannot figure out how this is done.

I have made some attempts:

```
img.Image convertYUV420ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
  final width = cameraImage.width;
  final height = cameraImage.height;

  final yRowStride = cameraImage.planes[0].bytesPerRow;
  final uvRowStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
  final uvPixelStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerPixel!;

  final image = img.Image(width:width, height:height);

  for (var w = 0; w < width; w++) {
    for (var h = 0; h < height; h++) {
      final uvIndex =
          uvPixelStride * (w / 2).floor() + uvRowStride * (h / 2).floor();
      final index = h * width + w;
      final yIndex = h * yRowStride + w;

      final y = cameraImage.planes[0].bytes[yIndex];
      int uvsByte = cameraImage.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];// U/V byte
      int u = uvsByte & 0xFF; // extract the first 8 bits (U value)
      int v = (uvsByte >> 8) & 0xFF; // extract the next 8 bits (V value)
      // final u = cameraImage.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
      // final v = cameraImage.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];

      image.data?.setPixel(w, h, yuv2rgb(y, u, v));
    }
  }
  return image;
}
```

But this results in a very green tinted image. [From this image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FYUV&psig=AOvVaw08JxZf_rnKLt0pj4qqJ-4L&ust=1678594044608000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA8QjRxqFwoTCPDGrKCA0_0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD), it seems like my U and V values are too low, which causes this.

I would really like some help in converting an iOS 2 plane YUV420 image to RGB, thank you!

Comment: I don't know this flutter language (?) but you seem to be picking up a single byte with `uvsByte = cameraImage.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];` and then you try to split it into two bytes on the following two lines. It seems unintuitive to me.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah you're right, I'm definitely doing something wrong. I'm not sure if iOS uses an interleaved plane (where alternating bytes hold u and v information) or if the data is somehow combined into one byte

Comment: I have upgrades my image library and need to migrate my existing functions over. I am also looking for a solution to YUV -> RGB

Comment: Hey @Tclha did you solve this issue? I also wonder how the iOS version of yuv420 needs to be interpreted correctly. Please consider writing an answer for your question in case you found out how it works